# Python: RecursionError with Class Inheritance

Tags: python, class, recursion, infinite-recursion

I have given a class `A` with methods `f` and `g`. In the implementation of `A.f`, the method `self.g` is called, i.e. `A.g` is used. (I am not able/willing to change this class `A` since it comes from a python package.)

Now I want to build a child class `B` of `A` and want to overwrite the methods `f` and `g`. In the implementation of `B.f`, I call `super().f`, i.e. `A.f` is used. In the implementation of `B.g.`, I call `self.f`, i.e. `B.f` is used.

I would expect that everything is well defined:
`B.g` calls `B.f` calls `A.f` calls `A.g`

In fact, I get a `RecursionError` as I am running into an infinite number of recursions:
`B.g` calls `B.f` calls `A.f` calls `B.g`

What do I not understand correctly?

Here is a implementation:

```
class A:
    def f(self):
        print('Method A.f was called.')
        self.g()

    def g(self):
        print('Method A.g was called.')

class B(A):
    def f(self):
        print('Method B.f was called.')
        super().f()

    def g(self):
        print('Method B.g was called.')
        self.f()

b = B()
b.g()
```

For clarification: In my application, `A` is a scikit-learn class, `f` is `fit` and `g` is `fit_transform`. In this scikit-learn class, `fit_transform` is explicitly overwritten, and `fit` unfortunately uses `fit_transform`. To ensure that my child class `B` does not inherit `fit_transform` from `A`, I have to redefine it in the usual way, and this leads to infinite recursion as explained.

Comment: `self.g()` is actually `b.g()` as in your initial call.

Answer (score 1):

The g method of B overwrites the one of A as you said, meaning A.f will call B.g, if you change the name of the method B.g your code will run as you expect it to

Comment: Is there a solution without changing the name of `B.g`? `A` is a scikit-learn transformer, `f` is `fit` and `g` is `fit_transform`. As this is standard terminology throughout scikit-learn and beyond, I want to avoid changing it for my subclass.

Comment: I think the solution given by rdas would work well in your case then

Comment: In this case, my subclass `B` does not inherit all the other attributes from `A`, I would have to access them in a more complicated way. I am (almost) sure that there is a more elegant solution to this. The critical point seems to `super()`, but I cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

> What do I not understand correctly?

Even though `self.g()` was called within `A.f`, the value that was passed as `self` is still an instance of `B`, so `B.g` is looked up by this operation rather than `A.g`.

It would help if you could explain what *problem you are trying to solve* with this structure. In particular, I don't understand why, for any *real-world* code, it would be useful within the B class for `g` to call upon `f`, but in the base class to do it the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

`self` is bound to the `B` object on which `.g()` was called.

Try replacing the inheritance with composition instead:

```
class A:
    def f(self):
        print('Method A.f was called.')
        self.g()

    def g(self):
        print('Method A.g was called.')

class B:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def f(self):
        print('Method B.f was called.')
        self.a.f()

    def g(self):
        print('Method B.g was called.')
        self.f()

a = A()
b = B(a)
b.g()
```

Output:

```
Method B.g was called.
Method B.f was called.
Method A.f was called.
Method A.g was called.
```